# Do the main gauche and Fighting Style: Two Weapons combine defensively?

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-1e, minds-eye-theatre, fighting-style

Using the MET core rules, do the defense bonuses for using a Main Gauche and Fighting Style: Two Weapons stack? i.e. If I have a character with a main-gauche and one dot of FS:TW, does he get two dots of defense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *main gauche* is not detailed in the **Mind's Eye Theatre** rulebook, so any decisions made about its effectiveness are going to depend on the Storyteller's judgment. (For example, if the weapon comes from the **Armory** rulebooks, compatibility with MET is not assured.) However, presuming that it works in a manner analogous to the rapier (p.232), then the answer is "yes": using the weapon will offer an additional +1 when using that merit, at the cost of breaking when an Ace is drawn.